# How to migrate django site to shared hosting

Tags: python, django

I do not django programer, python or linux :/ I have a  site.tar.bz2 with a db.sql and folders with multiple files .py and etc, i cant understand the structure. What have i to do to this? copy into public_html? my hosting is shared. :/

The content of folders:

[image]

thank you very much and i apologize for my english!

Comment: copying stuff over isn't enough, django needs to be installed on your new server along with python (for starters) this post could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850311/how-to-move-a-local-django-made-site-into-another-machine

Comment: [deploying djagno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/)

Comment: oh ok new world for me, thank you very much

Comment: I was researching and update my question. The host is shared, so I cant have access to everything... in example: ssh terminal.

Comment: It's unlikely that you will be able to run DJango applications on your shared hosting account.